# Error "Saw a start tag image." while validating HTML code

Tags: html, w3c-validation

I made something with the HTML code and trying to validate it through w3.org website. It was showing the following error:

> Error: Saw a start tag `image`.
>   From line 15, column 210; to line 15, column 290
>
> ```
> ="_blank"><image src="http://banglakitab.com/img/img_header.gif" height="48" width="128" /></a>
> ```

What could be wrong?

Answer (score 5):

Image tag in html :

```
<img src="source_of_image" alt="alternate text"  />
```

its not `<image />`.

Refer : [HTML Images](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_images.asp)

Comment: I just ran into the same issue.  You are absolutely correct, but using a misspelled tag  <image ... /> actually works too, at least on Chrome.  Weird.

Comment: @user949300 lot of such things are handled in chrome. Wouldn't work on other browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Your image tag is not valid you should use `img` tag instead of image.  And the image tag must have alternate (`alt`) property/attribute.

The `alt` attribute provides alternative information for an image if a user for some reason cannot view it (because of slow connection, an error in the src attribute, or if the user uses a screen reader).

```
 <img src="http://banglakitab.com/img/img_header.gif" height="48" width="128"  alt="banglakitab" />
```